# uninitialized constant but the table exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sure its a basic problem in RoR but I added a new table called hooods_one_providers. This table has no corresponding model - It should connects two models - Providers and Hoods. I am trying to call it in the console but getting instead - uninitialized constant.

When I run:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
=> ["schema_migrations", "users", "roles", "users_roles", "providers", "food_items", "food_items_users", "feedbacks", "addresses", "carts", "link_carts", "hoods", "drink_items", "addons_ons", "addons_nears", "customize_foods", "addresses_hoods", "hoods_one_providers"]
```

I can see the table but I cant read from it. When I run hooods_one_providers i get the uninitialized constant error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant HoodsOneProvider
    from (irb):14
    from /home/ido/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/ido/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/ido/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

In the model provider I have:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :hoods_one, class_name: 'HoodsOne'
```

And in the model hood I have:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :providers
```

Will appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: did you just add the table? Does the table have corresponding model in the code? Did you relaunch the console after adding the model?

Comment: I just added the table but relaunch the console. No corresponding model - It should connects two models - Provider and Hoods.

Comment: Post exact detailed error and the code that causes it.

Comment: "When I run hooods_one_providers" - when you run what?

Comment: I am trying to call the table as if I am calling the Provider table like so: Provider.find(1). But i also try to call it via some provider, like so: p=Provider.find 1 and than p.hoods_one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you've added the table while the console is running, the classes are already cached by the console.  Running `reload!` should fix the issue but in case it doesn't, a restart of the console should.

UPDATE:

You are using has_and_belongs_to_many which needs you to manually create the joins table.

UPDATE: creating the joins table

create a migration which contains the following to create the joins table.  the `id: false` option tells it not to create an `id` column

```
create_table :hoods_ones_providers, id: false do |t|
  t.references :hoods_one, :provider
end

add_index :hoods_ones_providers, [:hoods_one_id, :provider_id]
```

Comment: Hey. I did restart the console every time but didnt solve the problem.

Comment: How do I create the joins table?

Answer (score 4):

This could happen for any one of the cases below

1. Running `reload!` should fix.
2. Exit the console and run console again by `rails c`
3. Make sure the model file exists for the respective table. Let's assume your table name is `hoods_one_providers` then there should be `hoods_one_providers.rb` file under the model.